# Problem when Handling repeated error values on php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mariadb

I have a PHP program that connect to a MariaDB databse.

I upload name as "numbers" and i defined the value as UNIQUE so I don´t want to be repeatated.

However I would like to handle the error when a vlaue is repeated:

This is the table I created:

**Table in MariaDB**

```
create table test(
    ->     id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     name varchar(255) UNIQUE,
    ->     date DATE NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
```

**This is the script in PHP:**

```php
$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$connection = null;
$dt1=date("Y-m-d");
try{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db_name, $username, $password);
    $connection->exec("set names utf8");
}
catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
function saveData($name, $dt1){
    global $connection;
    $query = "INSERT INTO test(name, date) VALUES( :name, :date )";
    $callToDb = $connection->prepare( $query );
    $name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($name));
    //$dt1=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($dt1));
    $callToDb->bindParam(":name", $name);
    $callToDb->bindParam(":date", $dt1);

    if($callToDb->execute()){

        //return '<h3 style="text-align:center;">registration submmited!</h3>';
        //if (!$callToDb->execute()) {
        //    if ($callToDb->errno == 1062) {
        //    return '<h3 style="text-align:center;">VALUE REPEATED!</h3>';
        //    }
        //   else{
            return '<h3 style="text-align:center;">registration submmited!</h3>';
        //    }
        }
    }


    if( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
        $dt1 = htmlentities($_POST['date']);
        //then you can use them in a PHP function. 
        $result = saveData($name, $dt1);
        echo $result;
    }
    else{
        echo '<h3 style="text-align:center;">A very detailed error message</h3>';
    }
    //header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
}
```

the code part after `if($callToDb->execute()){` it is commented because it is not working but I would like to just show a message when the vlaue is repeated. The same than when a vlaue is registrated correctly.

**The issue to handle duplicate error is in this part which at the moment I am not using in my code as is not working fine**:

```php
if (!$callToDb->execute()) {
    if ($callToDb->errno == 1062) {
        return '<h3 style="text-align:center;">VALUE REPEATED!</h3>';
    }
    else{
       return '<h3 style="text-align:center;">registration submmited!</h3>';
    }
}
```

Any idea why this part of the code it is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code with this one.

```
$affected_rows = $callToDb->rowCount();
if (!$callToDb->execute())
{
    if ($affected_rows == 0)
    {
        return '<h3 style="text-align:center;">VALUE REPEATED!</h3>';
    }
    else
    {
        return '<h3 style="text-align:center;">registration submmited!</h3>';
    }
}
```

Comment: $stmt should be $query in my code, isn´t it?  I tried your code but it is not working. I replaced it for mine.

Comment: I updated the code. Please accept if it helps you.